# How to cleanly get a text file using AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax

See the code below. When the request is sent and comes back OK, in the `reqListener()` function, I get the contents of my text file output.

However, when I try to return the response variable later, it's still undefined, as if `reqListener()` hasn't been called yet. Could this be due to the `async=true` argument?

Furthermore, is there a neater way to get the response text out of the function should it the request be successful, like using a closure?

```
function load_text_file()
{
    function reqListener() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
                response = this.responseText;
                console.log(response);
        }
    }

    var response;
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onreadystatechange = reqListener;
    oReq.open("get", "file.txt", true);
    oReq.send();
    return response;
}

var TEXT = load_text_file();
console.log(TEXT);
```

Comment: The problem is, load_text_file() returns before the file has been loaded. Your function reqListener is called when the request actually completes. So, program flow goes something like this. (1) request file (2) return from proc, no result yet, so response is undefined. (3) console.log(TEXT) - response has not been returned yet. (4) Request completes, console.log(response) now has valid data to display.

Comment: AJAX = Asynchronous. Your function returns before it has loaded. Re-think your structure.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I can't assign the output of `reqListener` to anything since I don't know exactly when an `onreadystatechange` is going to happen. I mean, I could have a global variable TEXT and then assign TEXT to the `reponseText` in `reqListener()` but then that function is dependent on some external variable which seems gross.

Comment: For that matter, how is the XMLHttpRequest object even alive once the `load_text_file()` function is no longer on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request will take time to complete. You would be better off handing in a callback which fires when the file has loaded:

```
function load_text_file(callback)
{

    function reqListener() {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
                console.log(response);
                callback(this.responseText);

        }
    }


    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onreadystatechange = reqListener;
    oReq.open("get", "file.txt", true);
    oReq.send();
}

load_text_file(function(){
    console.log(TEXT);
});
```